# Device returns incorrect screen size

Tags: ios, screen-size, iphone-6

I use `[UIScreen mainScreen]` to determine the screen size, but now:

Running on the iPhone6 simulator:

`<UIScreen: 0x7faa31a161f0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7faa3050ccd0; size = 750.000000 x 1334.000000>>`

Running on the iPhone6 real device:

`<UIScreen: 0x156542ad0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x17422db80; size = 640.000000 x 1136.000000>>`

It was the wrong size.

I've tried:

1.Config the launchImage and appicon, the result remains the same.

2.Config the launchScreen file, the remains the same.

3.Using Xcode 6 new project, and config it, and run, the remains the same.

4.Download other developer's test project, the remains the same.

I can't find any reason to explain this problem, How can I let the real device to properly identify the screen size?

Comment: Could be a case-sensitivity issue. Double check the case - I have had problems where it's worked on the emulator but not on the device because of this.

Comment: @Rots I have already checked the launchImage name, I using images.xcassets  config it, and it's named as follows: Default.png、Default@2x.png、Default-568h@2x.png、Default-667h@2x.png、Default-736h--Landscape@3x.png...  is this wrong?

Comment: It depends if your filenames have the same case.

Comment: Has the device been set to zoomed mode? In that case, the result is right.